# error "a:5:{i:0;s:71:Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually"

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, permissions

I have moved my magento files from local server to live server. The site is running correctly and admin side login is working correctly. But when I click any menu links like "System->Configuration", it shows the below error in `var/report/` error file.

`a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually";i:1;s:3902:"#0 /httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(61923): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...'`

I have specified var/tmp folder manually in `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php` like

```
if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('\\temp')) {
            return '\\temp';
        }
    else{
        return 'var/tmp/';
    }
```

and

I have specified var/tmp path in `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` like

```
'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp/',
```

And folder permission  of var folder is 777 and also created folder in root called 'tmp'. But Still I am facing the issue.

How can I fix this issue ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open `.htaccess` file and put the line into it:

```
SetEnv TMP /your/magento/dir/var/session
```